# proof explanation of $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\notin \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I would like to understand the following proof of @Hw Chu

in this question [Prove that $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\notin \mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2734338/prove-that-sqrt-fracnn1-notin-mathbbq)

> If $\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \in \mathbb Q$, then $\displaystyle \sqrt{n(n+1)} = (n+1)\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \in \mathbb Q$, and since $n \in \mathbb N_{>0}$, $\sqrt{n(n+1)} \in \mathbb Z.$

Would someone elaborate this proof I mean proof step by step

Comment: See [$\sqrt a$ is either an integer or an irrational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4467). In this case $n(n+1)$ is an integer, and its square root is assumed to be rational, so it must be an integer.

Answer (score 5):

And then,
as has been shown here many times,
if $m$ is not the
square of an integer,
then $\sqrt{m}$ is irrational.

But $n^2 < n(n+1) < (n+1)^2$,
so $n(n+1)$ is not the
square of an integer,
so $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$
is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\in\Bbb{Q}$ then there exists $q\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $\frac{n}{n+1}=q^2$. Then 
$$n(n+1)=\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot(n+1)^2=q^2(n+1)^2,$$
so $\sqrt{n(n+1)}=q(n+1)\in\Bbb{Q}$. To see that this implies that $\sqrt{n(n+1)}\in\Bbb{Z}$, see the excellent answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number).

Answer (score 1):

We have

> If $\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \in \mathbb Q \implies \sqrt{n(n+1)} = (n+1)\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \in \mathbb Q$

that is a simple step by rationalization, then

> and since $n \in \mathbb N_{>0}$, $\sqrt{n(n+1)} \in \mathbb Z$

here since $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is a product of an integer and a rational number it must be an integer, indeed assume $\sqrt{n(n+1)}=\frac p q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ then $n(n+1)=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ and $\gcd(p^2,q^2)=1$ by FTA

> $n^2 < n(n+1) < (n+1)^2$.

this step prove that $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ can't be an integer.

Comment: A product of an integer and a rational number need not be an integer.

Comment: @Servaes even if it is in the form $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$?

Comment: I do not understand. Do you mean your rational number is $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}$ and your integer is $n+1$? Why would that imply that the product is an integer?

Comment: @Servaes the product is or rational or an integer but since it is in the form $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ it is an integer that is a rational $\frac a b$ with b=1.

Comment: Indeed the product is rational, possibly an integer. How the form $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ imply that it is an integer? This requires an argument, and likely a somewhat involved one.

Comment: @Servaes $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ rational $\implies n(n+1)$ is rational but $n(n+1)$ is integer thus $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is (supposed to be) an integer

Comment: The last implication is not easy, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/sqrt-a-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @Servaes but here we are working by the initial assumption that is $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \in \mathbb Q $ which implies that  $\sqrt{n(n+1)} = (n+1)\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: I agree; the assumption that $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}\in\Bbb{Q}$ implies that also $\sqrt{n(n+1)}\in\Bbb{Q}$. But to show that this implies $\sqrt{n(n+1)}\in\Bbb{Z}$ is not easy, see the question I linked before.

Comment: @Servaes It seems trivial to me, indeed assume $\sqrt{n(n+1)}=\frac p q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$ then $n(n+1)=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ and $\gcd(p^2,q^2)=1$ by FTA.

Comment: That is indeed very straightforward; I had a far more roundabout argument in mind for some reason, which blinded me. Unfortunately I can't retract my downvote unless there is an edit. Do you mind if I summarize this argument in your answer, or would you prefer to do that yourself?

Comment: @Servaes Finally we have clarified that point! I will add that to my answer!